# Unable to Call API using my identity server from a native application

Tags: c#, docker, xamarin, identityserver4

I would like to make a Identity server and the API in two separate dockers for a native application (client mobile).
It is running on an NGINX Reverse Proxy and Let's Encrypt.

```
                               Dockers
                     ---------------------------
                    |       Reverse Proxy       |
                    |  -----------------------  |
   --------         | |    ----------------   | |
  | Mobile | ---------|-> | IdendityServer |  | |
   --------         | |   |   Port: 5000   |  | |
       |            | |    ----------------   | |
       |            | |            |          | |
       |            | |    ----------------   | |
       ---------------|-> |      API       |  | |
                    | |   |   Port: 5001   |  | |
                    | |    ----------------   | |
                    |  -----------------------  |
                    |                           |
                    |      ----------------     |
                    |     |   PostgreSQL   |    |
                    |     |   Port: 5432   |    |
                    |      ----------------     |
                     ---------------------------
```

### With my current configuration:

- The Reverse Proxy with Let's Encrypt is well working from the mobile
- The call API without [Authority] is well working from the mobile
- The Identity server connection with the Hybrid flow is working and my user’s claims is listed

My codes are below.

### IdentityServer Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
COPY is4/* /app/
WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer.dll"]
```

### API Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
COPY api/* /app/
WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5001
EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiServer.dll"]
```

### DockerCompose

```
version: '3'

services:
  identityserver:
    image: identityserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    container_name: ids
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
#    expose:
#      - "5000"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 5000
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ids.mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ids.mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: myuser@mydomain.com
      IDENTITY_ISSUER: "https://ids.mydomain.com"
      IDENTITY_REDIRECT: "com.mobiletest.nativeapp"
      IDENTITY_CORS_ORIGINS: "https://ids.mydomain.com"
    depends_on:
      - db
  apiserver:
    image: apiserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiServer/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
#    expose:
#      - "5001"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 5001
      VIRTUAL_HOST: api.mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: api.mydomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: myuser@mydomain.com
      IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "http://identityserver:5000"
      CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS: "com.mobiletest.nativeapp"
    depends_on:
      - identityserver
      - db
    links:
      - identityserver
  db:
    image: postgresql:10
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PostgreSQL/Dockerfile
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /www/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: nginx-proxy
```

### IdentityServer Startup Code

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
    services.AddIdentityServer(opt =>
    {
        opt.IssuerUri = Configuration["IDENTITY_ISSUER"];
        opt.PublicOrigin = Configuration["IDENTITY_ISSUER"];
    })
    .AddCorsPolicyService<InMemoryCorsPolicyService>() // Add the CORS service
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

    services.AddAuthentication();

    // preserve OIDC state in cache (solves problems with AAD and URL lenghts)
    services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache("aad");

    // add CORS policy for non-IdentityServer endpoints
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
} // ConfigureServices()

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
} // Configure()
```

### IdentityServer Config Code

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile()
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        {
            ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) }
        }
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    // client credentials client
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "native.hybrid",
            ClientName = "Native Client (Hybrid with PKCE)",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
            RequirePkce = true,
            RequireConsent = false,
            //RequireClientSecret = false,
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },                   
            RedirectUris = { Configuration["IDENTITY_REDIRECT"] + "://signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { Configuration["IDENTITY_REDIRECT"] + "://signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile" },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = { Configuration["IDENTITY_CORS_ORIGINS"] },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            //AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse
        }
    };
} // GetClients()
```

### Api Config code

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddJsonFormatters();
    if (Configuration["CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS"] == "")
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .WithOrigins(Configuration["CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS"]));
        });
    }
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer");
    services.AddAuthentication(options => //adds the authentication services to DI
    {
        //We are using a cookie as the primary means to authenticate a user (via “Cookies” as the DefaultScheme). We set the DefaultChallengeScheme to “oidc” because when we need the user to login, we will be using the OpenID Connect scheme.
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")       //add the handler that can process cookies
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => //configure the handler that perform the OpenID Connect protocol
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies"; //is used to issue a cookie using the cookie handler once the OpenID Connect protocol is complete
            options.Authority = Configuration["IDENTITY_AUTHORITY"]; //indicates that we are trusting IdentityServer
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = "native.hybrid";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientSecret = "secret"; //used to persist the tokens from IdentityServer in the cookie
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        });

    services.AddMvc();
} // ConfigureServices()

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseMvc();
} // Configure()
```

### API Controller code

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "testvalue1", "testvalue2" };
    }
}
```

### On Xamarin for the client mobile

```cs
var options = new OidcClientOptions
{
    Authority = "https://ids4.syladebox.com",
    ClientId = "native.hybrid",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    //Scope = "openid profile api1 offline_access",
    Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
    ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

    RedirectUri = "com.mobiletest.nativeapp://signin-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "com.mobiletest.nativeapp://signout-callback-oidc",

    //Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid,
    //Policy = policy,

    //Browser = new SFAuthenticationSessionBrowser()
    // new in iOS 12
    Browser = new ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser()
    //Browser = new PlatformWebView()
};

_client = new OidcClient(options); 

var result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());

if (result.IsError)
{
    OutputText.Text = result.Error;
    return;
}

if (result.AccessToken != null)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken(result.AccessToken);
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.mydomain.com/api/values");
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
    {
        OutputText.Text = response.ReasonPhrase;
        return;
    }

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    OutputText.Text = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
}
```

### Problem not resolved:

The problem is to unable to invoke the API on behalf of my user. It returns either or "No authorized" either or "Bad gateway" after:

```cs
response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.mydomain.com/api/values");
```

These errors are depending of the environment variables in the IdentityServer and Api dockers.

My current environment variables are:

IDENTITY_ISSUER: "https://ids.mydomain.com"

IDENTITY_REDIRECT: "com.mobiletest.nativeapp"

IDENTITY_CORS_ORIGINS: "https://ids.mydomain.com"

IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "http://identityserver:5000"

CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS: "com.mobiletest.nativeapp"

The API call (https://api.mydomain.com/api/values) returns "Bad gateway".

I think that IDENTITY_ISSUER, IDENTITY_REDIRECT are corrects because the Identity server connexion is successful.

Is the problem coming from the other environment variables (IDENTITY_CORS_ORIGINS, IDENTITY_AUTHORITY and CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS) or the Identity Server/API codes?

### Update January, 26:

To make sure if my API program works, I redid the API program to the simplest:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = Configuration["IDENTITY_AUTHORITY"];
                     options.ApiName = "api";
                     //options.ApiSecret = "secret";
                 });

            // Add CORS policy for non-IdentityServer endpoints
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("api", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        } // ConfigureServices()

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCors("api");

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        } // Configure()
```

with the api controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "testvalue1", "testvalue2" };
        }
     }
```

and I use in my first test the other identity server :

**demo.identityserver.io**

For this test, I make the following configuration:

```
  apiserver:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    environment:
      ...
      IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "https://demo.identityserver.io"
      #CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS (omitted in the code)
```

My OidcClientOptions in the client code is:

```
            var options = new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
                ClientId = "native.hybrid",
                Scope = "openid profile email api offline_access",
                ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

                RedirectUri = "com.mobiletest.nativeapp://callback",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "com.mobiletest.nativeapp://callback",
                Browser = new ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser()
            };
```

The login function is in my first topic.

- The Identity server connection with the Hybrid flow is working
- The API call is successful!

As demo.identityserver.io is the demonstration identity server, I have a doubt if it works as the case of production then I tested an other identity server (Okta) with the same API program:

**dev-xxxxxx.okta.com**

For this test, I make the following configuration:

```
  apiserver:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    environment:
      ...
      IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "https://dev-xxxxxx.okta.com"
      #CLIENT_CORS_ORIGINS (omitted in the code)
```

My OidcClientOptions in the client code is:

```
            var options = new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://dev-xxxx.okta.com",
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // ClientId is hidden in this topic

                Scope = "openid profile email offline_access",
                ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

                RedirectUri = "com.okta.dev-xxxxxx:/callback",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "com.okta.dev-xxxxxx:/callback",

                Browser = new ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser()
            };
```

- The Identity server connection with the Hybrid flow is working
- The API call isn't working, it returns the message "Unauthorized".

With the two tests, I can not tell if my API program works well.

Could you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Xamarin isn't my thing but few things here:

 1. Is this valid? http://identityserver:5000. 
 2. If so why Authority = "https://ids4.syladebox.com"
 3. You are configuring https for "ids.mydomain" buy only exposing http in the docker image.

Comment: Also, try playing around with removing the cookies references.

Comment: Removing the cookies references? Could you explain me with more details? Thank you

Comment: See my answer below for the exposing http in the docker image

Comment: //options.SignInScheme = "Cookies"; <-- removing cookies and cookie scheme fixed issues I was having with IdSvr.

Comment: It still does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `.AddJwtBearer()` in your API instead of just `.AddAuthentication("Bearer")`?

Something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Audience = "api1";
    });
```

Source: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

While the source is referring to client credentials, I think you probably want to be using Jwt Tokens regardless of the client type.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I added these instructions
`services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["IDENTITY_AUTHORITY"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Audience = "api1";
    });`
with `Configuration["IDENTITY_AUTHORITY"] = "http://identityserver"`
.

The API call still returns "Bad Gateway".

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake: ids.mydomain.com instead of ids4.syladebox.com.

Yes I use https for ids.mydomain.com and I tested http in the API docker with the command:

```
docker exec -it api sh
```

and

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://identityserver:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

is not working 
but

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "identityserver:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

is successful (without http).

I change "http://identityserver:5000" to "identityServer:5000" in the environment variable IDENTITY_AUTHORITY and the APi call still returns "Bad Gateway" from the mobile application

Answer (score 0):

You have lots going on here and most likely have several issues to fix. Here are some things I noticed.

First up, You are attempting to access https://api.mydomain.com/api/values (which means https://api.mydomain.com:443/api/values) yet you have not exposed 443. Instead you have exposed http://api.mydomain.com:5001. Fix the Uri your client is trying to access first.

Then I would start with taking NGINX out of the mix and commenting our your Identity Server configuration in your API and making sure you can access you access the Web API.

Once you can access the Web API, then you can bring NGINX and Identity Server back into the mix one at a time and see if they are causing issues.

After that:

1. Go through your code and make sure your host names are consistent. For example, I am seeing several different urls/host names being used to point to your identity server. - http://identityserver:5000, https://ids.mydomain.com, https://ids4.syladebox.com. Make sure these are all using the same http scheme (http or https), same host name and same port.
2. Set up an API method to return your configuration variables to see what they are being set to. I am not seeing an reference to `ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables()` so I wonder if they are not be set and hence empty in your Configuration calls. Alternately, since you are having configuration issues you might want to hard code your configuration with magic strings and once you have things working move them to configuration/environment-able variables.
3. Make sure your environmental variables aren't being overwritten for example by [launch settings](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4159).
4. Not sure how you have NGNIX configured but you might need to expose https://*:[port] in your docker files like this. `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS https://*:5000` Both your Identity Server and API and simply exposing http://*:[port]

Answer (score 0):

Last week, Nginx was working badly. That's why I had the message "Bad Gateway" when I started the API call.
I relaunch it and the error message became "Internal Server Error"

Now,

**1. Reverse Proxy**

With removing [authorize], https://api.mydomain.com/api/values is working et well give:

```
0   "testvalue1"
1   "testvalue2"
```

https://ids.mydomain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration is also working.
I think than Nginx and Let's Encrypt are well working.

Are you agree?

**2. Environment variables**

I thought about that and I have tested the environment variables and I'm sure they are working.

I don't want to hard code my configuration for to test quickly to avoid recompiling the code and to upload it to my VPS.

The environment variables they must come from this code:

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
```

in Startup.cs

**3. Launch settings**

Identity server

```
    "IdentityServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
```

Api

```
    "Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001/"
    }
```

My environment variables used in the compose docker are not used in the launch settings then aren't being overwritten.

**4. Expose ports**

I have in the Dockerfile files

IdentityServer:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000
```

and Api:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5001
EXPOSE 5001
```

In the Docker-compose file, I have two possible configurations:

```
  identityserver:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5000:80
...
  api:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    environment:
      ...
      IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "http://identityserver"
```

Or

```
  identityserver:
...
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  ...
  api:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    environment:
      ...
      IDENTITY_AUTHORITY: "http://identityserver:5000"
```

These two configurations are working the same way.

Are you agree?

Should I use https in the docker network?

I will post here a topic for my tests with the two other identity servers: 
demo.identityserver.io and dev-xxxxxx.okta.com.

Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm not sure where your error is coming from looking at these configs.  Does this happen in your dev environment?  If so, monitor your output window while this error occurs.  This should give you more clues on where this error is coming from.

Comment: It is complicated because the applications are deployed in my VPN. DNS is pointed to this VPN, not to my PC where Visual Studio is installed. I have tested it on the local network (localhost) and it is working. The use of the public network (mydomain.com) impose to use the reverse proxy and the CORS. The applications are not working with this configuration